# Download file or send json in web api method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written web api in which it is returning/producing json response. Below is the code for the same.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("someapi/myclassdata")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public MyClassData GetMyClassData(int ID, int isdownload)
{
   myclassdata = myclassdataBL.GetMyClassData(ID);
   return myclassdata;

    //**Commented Code**
   //if(isdownload==1)
   //{
        //download file
   //}
   //else
   //{
        // send response
   //}
}
```

Till now it is working fine. Now I want to create and download the file based on value in '**isDownload**' parameter.

So after getting the data if files needs to be downloaded I want to download the file otherwise I will send the json response.

So, my question is can we send json reponse or download the file in same web api method.

Any help on this appreciated!

Comment: I would avoid using the same Web API method to return json in some cases or a file in other cases. Why don't you create 2 distinct Web API methods (one returns JSON and the other returns the file) and let the client application decide which one to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is easily achievable. Rather than returning `MyClassData` explicitly like that, you can return an `IActionResult`, like this:

```
public IActionResult GetMyClassData(int ID, int isdownload)
{
   myclassdata = myclassdataBL.GetMyClassData(ID);

   if (isDownload == 1)
       return File(...);

   return Ok(myclassdata);
}
```

Both `File(...)` and `Ok(...)` return an `IActionResult`, which allows for the dynamism you're asking for here.

Note: You can also just `return Json(myclassdata)` if you want to force JSON, but by default this will be JSON anyway and is more flexible with e.g. content-negotiation.

See [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more details.

Comment: So there is no need to have [Produces("application/json")] at top of the method ?

Comment: Personally, I've never needed to use `[Produces(...)]`. You don't *need* it here, but I believe it is also used by Swagger and such documentation-generation features. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1#forcing-a-particular-format) for more.

Comment: Yes, we are using swagger to test the APIs.. So, if I remove this still the json will be shown in swagger ?

Comment: Yes, assuming you're working with the defaults (this is likely), you will end up with JSON being returned. The benefit of using the `[Produces]` attribute generally is to inform Swagger that the response will indeed be JSON - it can also be used to document e.g. the status-codes that can be returned, as Swagger isn't always able to determine things like that for itself. You could also add something like `[Produces("application/pdf")]` if the file can return a PDF file, for example.

Comment: No problem at all. [This](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#explicit-responses) might also be helpful. You can be very descriptive of what will be returned from your actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180570/discussion-between-xamdev-and-kirk-larkin).